# Using jQuery variable as HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You're probably going to tell me to just do this all in jQuery, but I'm asking anyway.

I have an animation library that uses a counter to count from 0 to X. This was part of an HTML template I don't really want to modify.

I have built an AJAX script to GET the data I need to count to from a RESTful API source. Yes, I know, the api-key (secret) is still there, but there's no sensitive data and I'll cycle it after we're done here.

This HTML properly displays the value, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the value of the jQuery var $numClients into the "data-to" attribute.

Can anyone help me figure this out? I was hoping I could just reference the variable like "data-to=$varFromQuery" but I am a backend guy, not a JS guy, so I'm totally lost on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://path.to.url"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.totalTransferredGB').append(data.totalTransferredGB);
       $('.numClients').append(data.numClients);
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="counter-item">
            <span class="counter-number numClients" data-from="1" data-to="WHAT DO I PUT HERE" data-speed="20"></span>
             <span class="counter-text">Unique Devices Connected</span>
           </div>
```

EDIT:
I ended up solving it with the following code:

```
...then(function(data) {
       document.getElementById('totalGB').innerHTML=data.totalGB;
       document.getElementById('totalGB').setAttribute('data-to',data.totalGB);
       document.getElementById('numUsers').innerHTML=data.numUsers;
       document.getElementById('numUsers').setAttribute('data-to',data.numUsers);
       document.getElementById('numClients').innerHTML=data.numClients;
       document.getElementById('numClients').setAttribute('data-to',data.numClients);
    });
```

Comment: Update the element using jQuery `.prop()` or (better) jQuery `.data()` (if that's how the data attributes are being used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data()` method to update a data attribute on an element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://store.zapier.com/api/records?secret=5226d37cd13b40edbb97036f523d0a4e"
  }).then(function(data) {
    $('.totalTransferredGB').append(data.totalTransferredGB);
    $('.numClients').data('to', data.numClients);
    
    // for testing:
    console.log($('.numClients').data('to'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="counter-item">
  <span class="counter-number numClients" data-from="1" data-to="WHAT DO I PUT HERE" data-speed="20"></span>
  <span class="counter-text">Unique Devices Connected</span>
</div>
```

One caveat with this is that it does not update the DOM. The data is stored in an in-memory object which jQuery creates for better performance. If you require the `data-to` attribute within the DOM itself to be updated then you would need to use `attr()` instead:

```
$('.numClients').attr('data-to', data.numClients); // set the value
var numClients = $('.numClients').attr('data-to'); // get the value
```